# How to detect the change that from insert mode to normal mode, so I can implement Auto-Save?

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I want to do the following:

```
autocmd changeFromItoN * if &readonly == 0 && filereadable(bufname('%'))
                        \ | silent update | endif
```

That is: I want to implement the auto-save, so when I exit the insert mode and back to normal mode it will run `:w` automately. So what is the real command for `changeItoN`?

**Note**: This sounds like a little problem but actually there is a similar problem on SO that the accepted answer on that thread **won't** work with an important plugin which is used by a lot of people --- The CoC.nvim, and so I want to accomplish this feature myself :)

---

**Conclusion**: The command should be:

```
autocmd InsertLeave,TextChanged * if &readonly == 0 && filereadable(bufname('%'))
                                 \ | silent update | endif
```

Notice that the `TextChanged` is also needed so autosave will also work with daily-commands, e.g. after you delete a line by `dd`.

Comment: Have a look at `InsertLeave`.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer: I works :) If you're willing you might put it into an answer.

Comment: The way you broke your command into two lines is not correct. You need to put the backslash at the start of the second line. I guess when you tested your command you had everything in one line; otherwise Vim would have printed an error message.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer: Good catch! I think that's because I was writing python!

Comment: FYI [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events) lists the available events it might be useful next time you have a similar question. Also rather than using an autocommand you could go with a mapping like this: `inoremap <silent> jk <Esc>:update<CR>` You'd use `jk` to switch from insert mode to normal mode and it would save each time you switch mode. I've been using this for years and I'm perfectly happy with it.

Comment: @statox: While that way you cannot type "Dijkstra" in your text, so I still prefer moving my hand to press the `<Esc>` :P. (But thanks for your first part!)

Comment: Indeed, but occurrences of `jk` are pretty rare (at least in English and French) so this solution is quite popular because it's really rare that it creates an issue. Some people also like to use `jj` but whatever floats your boat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an autocommand event `InsertLeave`. It is triggered when you leave Insert mode permanently with <kbd>ESC</kbd> or temporarily with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, but not if you leave Insert mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: If you identity any problem on the command I provided in OP, you might also point it out :) Thank you so much!